# A question about continuous functions from a closed interval into itself

Tags: calculus, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f, g:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ be functions that are continuous on [a,b] such that $g$ is onto $[a,b]$, Must it be the case that $\exists x \in  [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$?

This statement sounds true from an intuitive point of view but how can I prove or disprove it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $c,d$ such as $g(c)=a, g(d)=b $ and consider also
$f-g$ on $[c,d]$.

details:

assume that $f(c)\neq g(c), f(d)\neq g(d)$ (otherwise you are done).

$$f(c)-g(c) > a-g(c)=0
\\
f(d)-g(d) < b-g(c)=0
$$
hence as $f-g$ is continuous, according to the intermediate values theorem,
there is a $X\in (c,d)\subset [a,b]$ such as $f(X)=g(X)$.